# Storing private data in jQuery widget, really private?

Tags: jquery, jquery-widgets

I search some time in the web to find a way to store data inside my widget, that can't be damaged or misused.

Most I found the recommendation to use this inside the widget.

```js
_init: function() {
  this._internalData = {};
},
```

But this data is not internal :(

```js
console.log($("#View1").JSTreeTable("").data().JSTreeTable._internalData);
```

The above code gives full access to the internal data.

Is there another way?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Using `var`, instead of `this` will make the data unobtainable from 'outside':

```
_init: function() {
  var _internalData = {};
}
```

Comment: You are joking ;) How will I access the data from another widget function?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. No need for the sarcasm though :( I'm not sure this can be done. The '_' does nothing as far as I am aware - it is more to show people reading your code that you intend that it is for 'private' use.